# Getting "The user has exceeded the number of videos they may upload" even though we have quota

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm getting "The user has exceeded the number of videos they may upload" even though we have quota left.  Is there a limit to number of video that can be uploaded?  It seems like our automation is running into this more recently and we have not changed our automation, it has been running for several months.  Thanks

Comment: If you could share us the number of videos your channel has uploaded, it may make more clear what is precisely the limit. Is it a permanent error or a transient error ?

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed another not documented enough limit, in addition to quota:

> **badRequest (400)**
>
> **uploadLimitExceeded**
>
> The user has exceeded the number of videos they may upload.

[Source](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert#errors)

As far as I know, we don't have more details, like the number of videos the user may upload...